# Install python package to PySpark Kernel in Sagemaker Notebooks

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-sagemaker

Has somebody figured out how to install packages on AWS Sagemaker Notebook  instances so they are available in the PySpark kernel? I made several attempts now including the lifecycle scripts but it seems I just miss the right python env. Package in question is `joblib` but I guess it shouldn't matter?!

Comment: They have provided the feature to pass requirements.txt in the sagemaker-python-sdk : https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/issues/52 . You could also look into one of the comments where user installed the required dependencies using a python script itself.

Comment: here we talk about the sagemaker sdk, right? I mean SageMaker Notebook instances. Will update my question

Comment: In that case maybe you could go through this aws documentation : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/nbi-add-external.html :-)

Comment: I did but this does not address/work for the PySpark kernel

Comment: You can install directly from a cell in the notebook that is running the relevant kernel using "!pip install ..."

Comment: nope not working...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for using Amazon SageMaker!

PySpark kernel unlike any other kernel is only running when there is EMR cluster to connect to. Whereas the Lifecycle Config runs before the Notebook Instance is put InService. So you cannot use Lifecycle Config to install packages in PySpark kernel, packages can only be installed after the kernel is started and connected to EMR cluster.

In order to install packages to PySpark kernel, you can do `pip install <package_name>` once the kernel is started up and it'll execute the command on EMR cluster master.

Thanks,

Neelam

Comment: pip isn't even installed by default on the attached EMR cluster or Pyspark kernel. Trying to run `pip install` directly off the "Launch terminal in current SageMaker Image" results in a package not found error

Answer (score 0):

You can install any package as follows:

```
sc.install_pypi_package("pandas==0.25.1")
```

See [this blog](https://repost.aws/questions/QU6jZ4ZGlaTvKIeFLBfilTgA/installing-additional-libraries-to-pyspark-kernel) for details.